# Facing issue with deploying safe contracts on mumbai testnet

Tags: gnosis-safe, hardhat-deploy, multisignature

I downloaded the safe contract latest release from https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/releases/tag/v1.4.0 and i am trying to deploy the contract . I am trying to run  npx hardhat --network mumbai  deploy-contracts .  I have added infura api key in .env , and other required api keys too but i am facing this error  when i run the script

Compiled 47 Solidity files successfully
failed to get chainId, falling back on net_version...
Error HH110: Invalid JSON-RPC response received: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32002,"message":"rejected due to project ID settings"}}

Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like there is a problem with your hardhat-cofig.js file ,  might be possible you are passing wrong chain id for the desired network to deploy. can you share the screenshot ? so i can figure out the issue

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not have need to re-deploy #safe contract because it is already deployed on Mumbai, please check the following ref. for the contract addresses "https://github.com/safe-global/safe-deployments/tree/main/src/assets/v1.3.0", Mumbai chain Id is 80001 so you can use the contract address for this chain Id.